# He's getting more bread at the new job,

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, slang

What does that mean?

I heard someone say, "he gettin more bread at the new company"

Does it mean more food, more salary, vacation or something entirely different?

Does it really mean he's getting a lot of ...bread?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bread is slang for money.  Getting more bread means getting more money.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you'd add sources. (if possible)

Comment: @shin: here ya go: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang_terms_for_money, http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/money, http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bread

Comment: "Something wrong,
I hold my head,
M.J. gone, our brother dead!
I slapped my girl, she called the feds,
I did that time and **spent that bread**"

Read more: Kanye West - All Of The Lights Lyrics | MetroLyrics

Comment: That's from a contemporary figure.  Still doesn't really bring home the point of using "bread" as a slang term for "money"...I'll try to find more :)

Answer (score 3):

One of the numerous slang words for "money" is "bread". It's a shortened form of "bread and honey" Cockney rhyming slang (a way of speaking using rhyming words, developed in the East End of London) for "money". [Here's the link](http://www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk/slang/bread_and_honey), and to make clearer how it works, [here are 15 more examples](http://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2012/10/the-brit-list-15-cockney-rhyming-slang).